# Why does an <a> with the same height and line-height within an <li> appear taller in Safari than in other browsers despite using a reset?

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

Here's a link to the site: http://nasracing.com/mobile/tal-moreeb/

The issue is with the 3 lines menu at the top.

In Chrome, Firefox and IE it works as intended. The #nav > li tags have a height of 14px which they get from the  tags within them (these  tags are set @ height: 14px; line-height: 14px;). However, in Safari the #nav > li tags renders with a height of 18px.

I can't see anything when inspecting the elements which would make this happen. Anyone got any ideas?

Edit: I am using a reset inspried by this one http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/. I have also tested normalize.css

Edit: Works fine in FF 29, Chrome 34, IE 8. Problem apparent in Safari 5+

Comment: Have you tried using a CSS reset to ensure it is not some proprietary browser CSS?

Comment: On a side note, that nav isn't very user friendly. The three lines in mobile have come to represent revealing 1 menu.

Comment: @Daniel,yep I'm using one.

Comment: @BrettSantore, yeah I completely agree. I am working with a designer, and although I have stated my case for usability he doesn't want to change it.

Comment: @jonahfree That's good, but please edit your original question to include that information. That is extremely important and relevant to those trying to help you (e.g. would've saved Barry time on his solution).

Comment: For reference, can you include which version of each browser you are using?

Comment: @Daniel have done that now.

Answer (score 3):

**Reason:**

The browser engine uses different default values, or (more likely in this case) units.

The example you mention might be caused by the engine using 1.1em instead of 1em for the `<li>` tag which would manifest itself in child elements, or use a non-`100%` percentage in a parent element. And then there are some browsers which (incorrectly) handle `%` and `em` units the same.

**Solution:**

Use a reset / normalize stylesheet, for example this one:
http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

**Tech bits:**

I wouldnt go here, but you could go and see what the difference is by comparing the [WebKit default stylesheet](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css) with that of other browsers. Also of use when investigating such issues in Chrome, it can show the inherited values per element: Right click the page element in Chrome, choose 'Inspect element', choose 'Computed' on the right, and check 'Show Inherited Properties'. Safari may have a similar feature or plugin.

Comment: I am using a reset, not normalize.css, but I have just tested that and no dice. As far as I know Chrome and Safari are both WebKit, so I don't understand why they should display differently?

Comment: @jonahfree Actually, Chrome uses [blink](http://www.sitepoint.com/blink-rendering-engine-google-chrome/). Also see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(layout_engine).

Comment: @Daniel ah, fair enough, I didn't know about that. Still uses a lot of the same vendor prefixes though.

Comment: @jonahfree Yes, sorry, I didn't mean to imply it was an entirely different engine. Considering Blink was branched not too long ago, it is probably still very similar. However they are *different* engines and thus you don't want to be operating on the assumption they are the exact same.

Comment: @Daniel very useful to know. I will definitely bear that in mind.

Comment: Try a new HTML document (no CSS), can you reproduce the problem there? If yes, its definitely the browser defaults to blame. If no, consider that your CSS is to blame: check for using wrong units in particular, also any non-100% or non-1em value is suspect.

Comment: Also, there are many `reset.css` or `normalize.css` solutions, you could try several.